# democratic rule

Tags: meaning

some explanations of "*rule*" vs "*govern*" from [quora.com](https://www.quora.com/What-can-be-the-difference-between-to-rule-and-to-govern):

> Rule - or ruling - implies ownership.
> if you’re governing it, you don’t own it; you’re just tasked with management and administration of it for a set period of time.

> Rule implies an autocracy.
> To govern implies that there is some level of public participation in the process.

> “Rule” has a stronger, more autocratic meaning. It would usually be used with a king or dictator.
> “Govern” would be used for an elected official like a president or prime minister.

one of the meanings of "*rule*" from [oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rule_1?q=rule) + an example:

> rule — the government of a country or control of a group of people by a particular person, group or system:
> *military/civilian/democratic rule*

According to the explanations above, "*rule*" is referred to an autocracy.
According to the examples from a dictionary, "*rule*" may not be referred to an autocracy.

Could you tell me please why do the collocations "*civilian rule*" and "*democratic rule*" contradict the explanations above?

Comment: @Joachim autocratic ≠ democratic

Comment: @Joachim I added two sentences with "_According ..._" Is it better now?

Comment: Quora is written by random people of no authority (much like Stack Exchange). Just because something is on Quora doesn't mean it's 100% infallible. Oxford Dictionaries aren't infallible either, but they're fairly trustworthy.

Answer (score 1):

**Democracy** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/democracy)) From Middle French democratie (French démocratie), from Medieval Latin dēmocratia, from Ancient Greek δημοκρᾰτῐ́ᾱ (dēmokratíā).
Surface analysis: demo- (“people”) +‎ -**cracy** (“rule”)

There you have it. I have bolded the 'cracy'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confuse the verbs "to rule"/"to govern" with the noun "(the) rule" here.

(The) "democratic rule" (or any other rule, for that matter) is, as you yourself wrote, the govern*ment* of a country. Govern*ment* is not the same as the way *to govern* it.

In case of the "democratic rule" the "rule" is roughly a synonym of "law". Law in itself has a sort-of "autocratic" connotation: you can't choose whether a certain law applies to you or not.

So: the *democratic rule* is to elect people (in a certain way) who in turn *govern* the country.